# How to use config.yml with DBAL

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dbal

how can i use "src/config/config.yml" with Doctrinbe DBAL.
Right now i'm using a static function that returns the config array DBAL needs to work with.

the static config file
src/config/AppConfig.php

```
protected static $dbserver = array(
    'dbname' => 'db-name',
    'user' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
);
```

within the contructor it looks like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->connect();
}

private function connect()
{
    $this->config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
    $this->conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection(AppConfig::getDbserver(), $this->config);
}
```

This is the Class of the Console Command

```
    namespace Mts\Command;

    use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

    use Mts\Utilities\SanitizeScan;


    class SanitizeScanCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
    {
        protected function configure()
        {
            $this->setName('sanitize:scan');
            $this->setDescription('Scan DB and Filesystem for invalid Filenames and write Result(s) to Log.');
        }

        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
            $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
            $question = new ChoiceQuestion(
                'Please Select what to Scan (defaults to both)',
                array('both', 'Database', 'Filesystem'),
                0
            );
            $question->setErrorMessage('%s is invalid.');
            $logtype = $helper->ask($input, $output, $question);

            # get config.yml from src/config/
            $conn = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
            print_r($conn);

            $log = new SanitizeScan($logtype);
            $log->create();
        }
    }
```

Target is to use this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname:               
        host:                 localhost
        port:                 3306
        user:                 
        password:             
        driver:               pdo_mysql
        charset:              UTF8
        logging:              '%kernel.debug%'
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Controller you can get doctrine with

```
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
```

In a custom Class you can inject the service container and than

```
$doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
```

and than from doctrine you can get the connection

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection $conn
 */
$conn = $doctrine->getConnection();
```

see also [How to Use Doctrine DBAL](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html)

**Update - minimal working example**

in a command you can use the ContainerAwareCommand

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class TestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('app:test');
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $conn = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
        dump($conn);
    }
}
```

see [Console - Getting Services from the Service Container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container)

Comment: Hi, i can't get it working. I should mention that i'm new to Symfony and PHP.  I was reading the Docs up and down, but no success. In my case i'm using Symfony to create Console Commands

Comment: Hi, now i get an error `Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Application::getKernel()`

Comment: Hi, i've updated my Post. Please see section "This is the Class of the Console Command"

Comment: I've given you a minimal example which works in my environment. If that doesn't work the bug has to be somewhere else in your environment. also note dump() which has a nicer output format. Maybe try it on a fresh symfony3 project...